# How to validate website URL field of an JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I have a JPA entity representing a company. It has a field representing the company's website URL. I need to validate that the URL is a valid website URL prior to persisting. I suppose only URLs starting with http or https would be valid website URLs. How can I enforce this? I'm using the latest. version of Hibernate as my JPA provider.

Comment: For better illustration: JPA annotation are on data (model). Live effects of validation should be seen on GUI layer. Something must connect both. The best is use complete framework (web framework for web app), not 'manual' code,

Comment: JPA is NOTHING to do with Bean Validation. That is the Bean Validation API

Answer (score 11):

@dimitrisli suggests you a correct solution. You should use `@URL` constraint. If you want to allow a specific protocol - there's a `protocol` attribute for this constraint:

```
@URL(protocol = "http")
private String companyUrl;
```

In addition there's also a `regexp` attribute which you can use to make your urls to match any pattern you'd like.

```
    @URL(regexp = "^(http|ftp).*")
    private String companyUrl;
```

You can check for more details in the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints) (look for URL in the linked section).

Also if you'd like to use the `URL` instead of String, you can write your own validator implementation for `URL` class and `URL` constraint, but note if you'd try to create an invalid `URL` it will fail during creation process and not when validated. So writing a validator for `URL` might make sense only if you'd like to check the protocol and things like that.

To write your own validator you would need to implement

```
public class URLValidator implements ConstraintValidator<org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL, URL> {
...
}
```

for more details check out [this](http://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/) blog post.

Comment: The regexp doesn't work for me. If I validate https://www.google.com against the URL validator with the  regexp = "^(http|https)" , it fails validation.

Comment: Right... It's because it's trying to match that expression to a `String` value and in your case of google - it doesn't start with protocols. ..
But is it a valid URL though ? (I mean if it's without a protocol)

Comment: I figured it out. It's because the regexp is matching the whole string not just the occurrence of the sibstring. I needed to add .* such that the regexp = "^(http|https).*"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [@URL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.html) annotation of Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Thanks. That means I would need to represent the website URL field as a 'String' instead of a 'java.net.URL'. I suppose that is OK. But how do I specify multiple protocols such as 'http' and 'https'. The '@URL' 'protocol' attribute only takes a single 'String'. Don't think I should allow protocols such as 'file', 'ftp', etc.